# Power Function for very large numbers

Tags: java, math

I need to get the result of a 16 byte number to the power of a 32 bit number:

funcResult = 16 byte number ^ 32 bit

I have tried many options, but the result is either infinity or error. And obviously regular BigInteger is no match for this.
What other options do I have?

Comment: Do you need all the digits?  An approximation?

Comment: "obviously BigInteger is no match for this" - why obviously? Explain your statement.

Comment: Yes, all the digits are required @LouisWasserman

Comment: @rouiz: Why don't you use BigInteger?

Comment: Regular BigInteger(without an increase in heap size) is simply not enough to store all the digits. @mentallurg

Comment: @rouiz: Increase memory for your program. See the answer below.

Comment: @rouiz: Does it work?

Comment: @rouiz A "16 byte number ^ 32 bit" number can have more than **82 *billion* digits** (up to 82,100,038,104 digits). Why would you need such a number? What would you do with it? A 32 bit key is at most 10 digits, so how did you intend to compress 82,100,038,104 digits down to 10? Your question makes no sense, and is likely an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/351454).

Comment: Still trying to implement, the number is too large, will tell you the result when it's over. @mentallurg

Comment: I am obligated to rewrite the RSA algorithm using only a 32 bit key(due to hardware deficiency). and I need to do all parts manually since 32 bit RSA is not common (or even useful frankly) @ArvindKumarAvinash

Comment: I am obligated to rewrite the RSA algorithm using only a 32 bit key(due to hardware deficiency). and I need to do all parts manually since 32 bit RSA is not common (or even useful frankly)  @Andreas

Comment: @rouiz: Why are you implementing it? 1) Java has already classes that provide everything what you need for RSA: Key generation, encryption, decryption. 2) Implementing encryption by yourself has a high risk that such implementation is not secure, e.g. your implementation may have side channels with high leakage, which will make the whole encryption useless. Why do you want to implement instead of using ready Java classes for this?

Comment: Please put the need to rewrite the RSA algorithm into your question. This is obviously solvable since it has been done before. It just might need another way to do it.

Comment: RSA Java class doesn't accept generation of a key that has less than (about) 512 bits length. I tried that first @mentallurg

Comment: @rouiz: Check https://www.bouncycastle.org before implementing everything from scratch. I have not used it with such short keys. Let us know if it works :)

Comment: Of course, I will gladly share the result, thanks for your kind feedback ;) @mentallurg

Comment: You *never* need to do this in RSA. Instead, in RSA you do modular exponentiation smartly. [`BigInteger.modPow()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#modPow-java.math.BigInteger-java.math.BigInteger-) is the function you'd use. Intermediate value never get much bigger than the modulus.

Comment: `BigInteger` can do this without trouble with `modPow`, which is enough for RSA.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a variable type in Java bigger than BigInteger. Try increasing the heap size.

```
java -Xmx256m MyClass.java

Xmx- Max Heap Size
```

You may find this helpful:

https://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0131.html

Comment: I increased the heap size but still it only accepts 9 digits of power, when I add the tenth number , says "Integer number too large".